# Object literal with constants as keys (in key value pair)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, object-literal

I have a class that holds some constants and will receive an *object literal* (associative array) with some data like this:

```
var ConfigObj:Config = new Config({
    "Some" : 10,
    "Other" : 3,
    "Another" : 5
});
```

The class looks like this:

```
public dynamic class Config
{
    static public const SomeProperty:String = "Some";
    static public const OtherProperty:String = "OtherProperty";
    static public const AnotherProperty:String = "AnotherProperty";

    public function Config(settings:Object)
    {
        // Doing some stuff here
    }
}
```

The problem is, how can I pass the constants as *keys* like this:

```
var ConfigObj:Config = new Config({
    Config.SomeProperty : 10,
    Config.OtherProperty : 3,
    Config.AnotherProperty : 5
});
```

Besides, I would like to keep it inline, if possible.

```
var MyObj:MyClass = new MyClass({x:1, y:2, z:3});
```

is, for me, far better than:

```
var Temp:Object = new Object();
Temp.x = 1; // Or Temp[x] = 1;
Temp.y = 2; // Or Temp[y] = 2;
Temp.z = 3; // Or Temp[z] = 3;

var MyObj:MyClass = new MyClass(Temp);
```

Comment: Actually your first example will compile without the double-quotes. They're optional (as long as the keys follow identifier naming rules, as yours do). Unfortunately this kind of "substitution" is not supported by the {} syntax.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think I see what you're trying to do (sort of). You may want to look into Flash's Dictionary class; it may provide the key-value pairs you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get the feeling that you're over-complicating your configuration object, however if you do want to use constants to set key-value pairs, you'll need to use a temporary variable:

```
var o:Object, configObj:Config;
o = {};
o[Config.SomeProperty] = 'foo';
o[Config.OtherProperty] = 'bar';
o[Config.AnotherProperty] = 'baz';

configObj = new Config( o );
```

An important question to ask: are these properties truly constant? If they are, then there's little risk in using the string literal when you instantiate the object:

```
new Config( { 'SomeProperty':'foo', 'OtherProperty':'bar', 'AnotherProperty':'baz' } );
```

Of course, this *isn't* flexible if the values in the constants change.

Comment: Well, I'm using constants just because I need to keep the integrity of the code... I can't rely solely on strings, I need the compile-time checking, and using constants ensure that. Other thing is, I would like it to be inline, and creating another object to keep the temporary data isn't a good way to do it.

Comment: @NemoStein, then why aren't you using parameters? Alternatively, why can't you set properties directly on the Config object, which would then remove the need for a placeholder object to begin with. Wanting everything to be inline is overrated and less readable.

Comment: I agree with *"overrated and less readable"*... Still, my boss don't! About using parameters, it should come in a specific order, but my config class uses a bit long list of parameters and the user should not pass every one, and not even ordered... And setting it directly on Config object would break the "inline" style...

Comment: There's no (simple) way of using constants as keys in one line. I'd suggest just using the string-literals, and not worrying about the constants. Make sure that you have reasonable defaults in the config class, and avoid changing the names.

Comment: When you've gotta pass in many different configuration objects as parameters to many method calls, creating object variables and setting each property individually for each object in each call gets very bloated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enforce type checking and parameter naming you should not use a `dynamic class` or passing an `Object` , but you should code a `Config class` with all the possibilities that are available.
Returning the `Config class` while setting a paremeter will allow you to inline the call.
It requires more works but it's safer IMHO.

Ex:

```
class Config {
    protected var _somePropertySet:Boolean
    public function get isSomePropertySet():Boolean{
        return _somePropertySet
    }
    protected var _someProperty:String;
    public function setSomeProperty(value:String):Config{
        _somePropertySet=true
        _someProperty = value
        return this
    }
    public function get someProperty():String{
        return _someProperty
    }

    protected var _someOtherPropertySet:Boolean
    public function get isSomeOtherPropertySet():Boolean{
        return _someOtherPropertySet
    }
    protected var _someOtherProperty:int;
    public function setSomeOtherProperty(value:int):Config{
        _someOtherPropertySet=true
        _someOtherProperty = value
        return this
    }

    protected var _someAnotherPropertySet:Boolean
    public function get isSomeAnotherPropertySet():Boolean{
        return _someAnotherPropertySet
    }
    protected var _someAnotherProperty:Object;
    public function setSomeAnotherProperty(value:Object):Config{
        _someAnotherPropertySet=true
        _someAnotherProperty = value
        return this
    }
}

class Tmp {
    public function Tmp(config:Config) {
        initFromConfig(config)
    }

    protected function initFromConfig(config:Config):void {
        if (config.isSomePropertySet){
            //..
        }
        if (config.isSomeOtherPropertySet){
            //..
        }
        if (config.isSomeAnotherPropertySet){
            //..
        }
    }
}
var t:Tmp=new Tmp(new Config().setSomeProperty("foo").setSomeOtherProperty(5).setSomeAnotherProperty(null))
```